# ASP.net Publish to server using default membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have published my website to a live server by using *Build -> Publish Web site*.
I am using default membership of asp.net.

I've got this message after using login on my website:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[SqlException (0x80131904): Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +2074350
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) +5066444
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() +234
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +2275
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +215
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) +987
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) +162
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) +178
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +137
   System.Web.Util.SecUtility.CheckSchemaVersion(ProviderBase provider, SqlConnection connection, String[] features, String version, Int32& schemaVersionCheck) +392
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckSchemaVersion(SqlConnection connection) +84
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +827
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +106
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AuthenticateUsingMembershipProvider(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +60
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnAuthenticate(AuthenticateEventArgs e) +129
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.AttemptLogin() +127
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Login.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +37
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnCommand(CommandEventArgs e) +125
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1008
```

my web config is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
  <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Server=192.168.101.114;Database=user;Initial Catalog=user;User ID=mehr1;Password=ww@123; "
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=192.168.101.114;Database=user;Initial Catalog=user;User ID=mehr1;Password=ww@123;"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
        <membership>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
     name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
   </providers>
  </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I'm using dot framework 4, asp.net default template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

information from stack trace:

```
1. "Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion"..
2. Your stored oprocedure of the above name doesnot exist in the host.
3. Make a script of the same from local and run it in host.
4. This will solve your problem.
```

Comment: how to do it? i am beginner!

Comment: go to sql server in your machine.right click on your database,tasks-generate scripts.A dialog will be opened.click next,then select stored procedure and finally you are done.Then connect your host database with the id given by ur domain provider and run it in your  machine and select particular database and run script in it.thats it

Comment: @wudzik,the stack trace only states this as error. Isn't it.The thing is he have given a wrong title to the question..